# Не работает форма main.feedback [Битрикс]

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, при отправки письма я получаю ошибку от frontend с ошибкой "При отправке сообщения произошла ошибка". И данные json не уходят с backend на frontend.

Frontend (JS)

```
import Alert from './Alert.js'
import Helper from './Helper.js'

let forms = []

export default class Form {
constructor(form) {
    this.form = form

    this.submit_handler = this.submit.bind(this)
    this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.submit_handler)


    this.type = this.form.querySelector('[name=type]') || null

    this.submit_button = this.form.querySelector('[type=submit]')
}

async submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (Form.valid(this.form)) {
        this.submit_button.disabled = true

        await Helper.recaptha()

        const data = new FormData(this.form)
        data.append('action', 'mailer')

        let response = await fetch(window.ajax, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })

        response = await response.json()

        if (response.success) {
            this.form.reset()
            // Проверка response = await response.json()

            if (this.type) {
                switch (this.type) {
                    case 'start' :
                        ym(91396360,'reachGoal','start_project')
                        break;
                    case 'consultation' :
                        ym(91396360,'reachGoal','consultation')
                        break;
                    case 'brief' :
                        ym(91396360,'reachGoal','brif')
                        break;
                    case 'get-project' :
                        ym(91396360,'reachGoal','order_project')
                        break;
                    case 'get2' :
                        ym(91396360,'reachGoal','portfolio')
                        break;
                }
            }

            // location.href = window.success
                location.href = '/success/'
        } else if (response.error) {
            Alert.add(response.error, 'error')
        } else {
            Alert.add('При отправке сообщения произошла ошибка', 'error')
            // Проверка throw new Error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса')
        }

        this.submit_button.disabled = false
    } else {
        Alert.add('Заполните все обязательные поля', 'error')
    }
}

static reInit() {
    if (forms.length) {
        forms.forEach(form => {
            form.form.removeEventListener('submit', form.submit_handler)
        })

        forms = []

        Form.init()
    }
}

static valid(form) {
    let valid = true

    form.querySelectorAll('.required').forEach(required => {
        if (required.querySelector('[type=radio]') && !required.querySelector('[type=radio]:checked')) {
            valid = false

            required.classList.add('required-active')

            setTimeout(() => {
                required.classList.remove('required-active')
            }, 5000)
        } else if (required.querySelector('input') && (required.querySelector('input').value == 0 || required.querySelector('input').value == '')) {
            valid = false

            required.classList.add('required-active')

            setTimeout(() => {
                required.classList.remove('required-active')
            }, 5000)
        } else if (required.querySelector('textarea') && (required.querySelector('textarea').value == 0 || required.querySelector('textarea').value == '')) {
            valid = false

            required.classList.add('required-active')

            setTimeout(() => {
                required.classList.remove('required-active')
            }, 5000)
        }
    })

    return valid
}

 static init() {
    const _forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form')

    if (_forms.length) {
        _forms.forEach(form => forms.push(new Form(form)))
    }
}
   }

  Form.init()
```

Backend (PHP)

```
                            <?php
                        if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED")||B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

                        /**
                         * Bitrix vars
                         *
                         * @var array $arParams
                         * @var array $arResult
                         * @var CBitrixComponent $this
                         * @global CMain $APPLICATION
                         * @global CUser $USER
                         */

                        $arResult["PARAMS_HASH"] = md5(serialize($arParams).$this->GetTemplateName());

                        $arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"] = (($arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"] != "N" && !$USER->IsAuthorized()) ? "Y" : "N");
                        $arParams["EVENT_NAME"] = trim($arParams["EVENT_NAME"]);
                        if($arParams["EVENT_NAME"] == '')
                            $arParams["EVENT_NAME"] = "FEEDBACK_FORM";
                        $arParams["EMAIL_TO"] = trim($arParams["EMAIL_TO"]);
                        if($arParams["EMAIL_TO"] == '')
                            $arParams["EMAIL_TO"] = COption::GetOptionString("main", "email_from");
                        $arParams["OK_TEXT"] = trim($arParams["OK_TEXT"]);
                        if($arParams["OK_TEXT"] == '')
                            $arParams["OK_TEXT"] = GetMessage("MF_OK_MESSAGE");

                        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["submit"] <> '' && (!isset($_POST["PARAMS_HASH"]) || $arResult["PARAMS_HASH"] === $_POST["PARAMS_HASH"]))
                        {
                            $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"] = array();
                            if(check_bitrix_sessid())
                            {
                                if(empty($arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"]) || !in_array("NONE", $arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"]))
                                {
                                    if((empty($arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"]) || in_array("NAME", $arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"])) && mb_strlen($_POST["user_name"]) <= 1)
                                        $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_REQ_NAME");
                                    if((empty($arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"]) || in_array("EMAIL", $arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"])) && mb_strlen($_POST["user_email"]) <= 1)
                                        $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_REQ_EMAIL");
                                    if((empty($arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"]) || in_array("MESSAGE", $arParams["REQUIRED_FIELDS"])) && mb_strlen($_POST["MESSAGE"]) <= 3)
                                        $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_REQ_MESSAGE");
                                }
                                if(mb_strlen($_POST["user_email"]) > 1 && !check_email($_POST["user_email"]))
                                    $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_EMAIL_NOT_VALID");
                                if($arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"] == "Y")
                                {
                                    // $captcha_code = $_POST["captcha_sid"];
                                    // $captcha_word = $_POST["captcha_word"];
                                    // $cpt = new CCaptcha();
                                    // $captchaPass = COption::GetOptionString("main", "captcha_password", "");
                                    // if ($captcha_word <> '' && $captcha_code <> '')
                                    // {
                                    //  if (!$cpt->CheckCodeCrypt($captcha_word, $captcha_code, $captchaPass))
                                    //      $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_CAPTCHA_WRONG");
                                    // }
                                    // else
                                    //  $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_CAPTHCA_EMPTY");


                                }
                                if(empty($arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"]))
                                {
                                    $arFields = Array(
                                        "AUTHOR" => $_POST["user_name"],
                                        "AUTHOR_EMAIL" => $_POST["user_email"],
                                        "EMAIL_TO" => $arParams["EMAIL_TO"],
                                        "TEXT" => $_POST["MESSAGE"],
                                    );
                                    if(!empty($arParams["EVENT_MESSAGE_ID"]))
                                    {
                                        foreach($arParams["EVENT_MESSAGE_ID"] as $v)
                                            if(intval($v) > 0)
                                                CEvent::Send($arParams["EVENT_NAME"], SITE_ID, $arFields, "N", intval($v));
                                    }
                                    else
                                        CEvent::Send($arParams["EVENT_NAME"], SITE_ID, $arFields);
                                    $_SESSION["MF_NAME"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["user_name"]);
                                    $_SESSION["MF_EMAIL"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["user_email"]);
                                    $event = new \Bitrix\Main\Event('main', 'onFeedbackFormSubmit', $arFields);
                                    $event->send();
                                    LocalRedirect($APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("success=".$arResult["PARAMS_HASH"], Array("success")));
                                }

                                $arResult["MESSAGE"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["MESSAGE"]);
                                $arResult["AUTHOR_NAME"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["user_name"]);
                                $arResult["AUTHOR_EMAIL"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST["user_email"]);
                            }
                            else
                                $arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"][] = GetMessage("MF_SESS_EXP");
                        }
                        elseif($_REQUEST["success"] == $arResult["PARAMS_HASH"])
                        {
                            $arResult["OK_MESSAGE"] = $arParams["OK_TEXT"];
                        }

                        if(empty($arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"]))
                        {
                            if($USER->IsAuthorized())
                            {
                                $arResult["AUTHOR_NAME"] = $USER->GetFormattedName(false);
                                $arResult["AUTHOR_EMAIL"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($USER->GetEmail());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if($_SESSION["MF_NAME"] <> '')
                                    $arResult["AUTHOR_NAME"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_SESSION["MF_NAME"]);
                                if($_SESSION["MF_EMAIL"] <> '')
                                    $arResult["AUTHOR_EMAIL"] = htmlspecialcharsbx($_SESSION["MF_EMAIL"]);
                            }
                        }

                        if($arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"] == "Y")
                            $arResult["capCode"] =  htmlspecialcharsbx($APPLICATION->CaptchaGetCode());

                        $this->IncludeComponentTemplate();
```

Только начал изучение программирования. Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка и как ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

Давайте разберём код. Вернее его условия.

```js
const data = new FormData(this.form)
data.append('action', 'mailer')

let response = await fetch(window.ajax, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
})

response = await response.json();

if (response.success) {
    /**
     * ....................
    */
} else if (response.error) {
    Alert.add(response.error, 'error')
} else {
    Alert.add('При отправке сообщения произошла ошибка', 'error')
    // Проверка throw new Error('Ошибка при выполнении запроса')
}
```

На каком условии у вас ошибка?

Что в консоли, если проверить ответ?:

```js
    const data = new FormData(this.form)
    data.append('action', 'mailer')

    let response = await fetch(window.ajax, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })

    response = await response.json();
    
    console.log(response);
```

Какой ответ (код ответа сервера) возвращает ваш запрос?

Comment: В консоле ошибка "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON". Но само письмо на почту приходит.

Comment: Всё правильно. У вас пришла HTML страница, а не JSON ответ.
Вот и смотрим в инструментах разработчика, что именно пришло.

Comment: Там пришла страница главная в html. Больше ничего в консоли нет.

Comment: И??? Значит вы посылаете запрос ни на ту страницу, либо у вас не настроен ответ получения формы, либо не настроено почтовое событие для данной формы. Нюансов много...